# Clear all cookies from browser does not sign out users from Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc, microsoft-graph-api

I have set specific cookie expiration policies in my Azure AD setup in my program.cs file however regardless of if the cookie expires refreshing the page just reloads all the cookies back again instead of forcing them to relogin. Is this not controlled by ASP.NET Core? I cannot figure out how to do this. I want a user to have to relogin if the cookie is no longer valid as it starts to cause CORS errors on the page once it expires for every api call it makes to my controllers (all of which use Authorize tag).

My program.cs is as follows:

```
    //authentication pipline
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
var initialScopes = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
                {
                    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
                    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                    {
                        //Tap into this event to add a UserID Claim to a new HttpContext identity
                        OnTokenValidated = context =>
                        {
                            //This query returns the UserID from the DB by sending the email address in the claim from Azure AD
                            string query = "select dbo.A2F_0013_ReturnUserIDForEmail(@Email) as UserID";
                            string connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("ConnectionStrings:DBContext");
                            string signInEmailAddress = context.Principal.FindFirstValue("preferred_username");

                            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                            {
                                var queryResult = connection.QueryFirst(query, new { Email = signInEmailAddress });

                                var claims = new List<Claim>
                                {
                                    new Claim("UserID", queryResult.UserID.ToString())
                                };

                                var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);

                                context.Principal.AddIdentity(appIdentity);
                            }

                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        },
                    };

                }, CookieOptions =>
                {
                    CookieOptions.SlidingExpiration = true;
                    CookieOptions.LoginPath = "/Login/";
                    CookieOptions.LogoutPath = "/Logout/";
                    CookieOptions.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
                })
                    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
                        .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

I was hoping once that cookie expires it would force them to the login path indicated in the cookie options on the next page refresh or API call to the controller but it does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I trust you already noticed that, when you integrate Azure AD into your app, you can sign in by redirect to microsoft identity page, and when you want to sign out, you also need to redirect to microsoft identity page to choose an account to sign out. And this is why you can't set the user login expire time by only changing the cookie lifetime.

You signed in identity platform and Azure AD will give your app an id token, then the cookie authentication in your local app will generate cookie value and stored it in the browser. When you delete the cookie or it has been expired, it should redirect back to microsoft identity page, but actually the user already signed in with the microsoft account and the sign in information hasn't been expired that time so that it wouldn't require to enter username/password but return with the id token directly. Finally a new cookie was generated and authentication done.

According to your requirement, I'm afraid you can going to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-session-lifetime) to find a good policy for you to set up in your Azure AD, you need to use the `Conditional Access Administrator, Security Administrator, or Global Administrator account` to sign in Azure portal to set the policy. Going to `Azure Active Directory > Security > Conditional Access` for adding the policy. But it require Premium pricing tier.

[image]

Comment: that's not an option for us...because AAD had SSO by default, so we have to redirect to the signout page...

Comment: Wait you redirect to MS signout page on cookie expiration? Do you set an event for this? Also, any reasons why when the cookie expires it starts to cause CORS errors on the front end fetch calls to the apis? Surprised the MS login lasts longer than the cookie lifetime for the default cookie settings in MS Azure integrations for their SDK.

Comment: `CORS errors` can only be solved at the api side, and I'm not sure why the expired cookie would cause it, basically when the  api allowed the client app's origin by a cors policy, there shouldn't be a cors issue... I mean you may try to set allow any origin and allow any method and test again.

Comment: I don't set an event for cookie expiration. when cookie is expired, the request to your app should be recognized as unauthenticated, so it will automatically redirect to sign in page, just like the first time you visit your app. by the way, you also mentioned the api, when we protect api with azure AD, it should be protected by access token(authorization), but not the cookie, cookie should be used in the client app(e.g. SPA) for authentication.

Comment: The issue is when the cookie expires on the front end in our VueJS SPA, doing any further api requests to our controllers (asp.net core mvc) causes this error Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/blah blah blah....redirected from 'https://localhost:44362/API/test') from origin 'https://localhost:44362' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. I think this has to do with the redirect to MS login you mention above. The SPA API request are forwarded from controller to MS login by default

Comment: I'm afraid this issue related with the `CookieOptions` you set in your api. and I have several ideas. firstly, could you pls check if you set the http(s)://localhost as the redirect url for both SPA and web app platform in azure ad portal? If not, you may try it. Then I think you can also comment the `CookieOptions` in your web api. Here's a [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code#web-api) for AAD protect api.

Comment: If I refresh the page the cors error go away. So refreshing generates a new cookie without having to relogin since as you said above the MS login server still assumes the user is logged in despite the cookie has expired on the client side.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So I have localhost as a redirect URI in Azure AD App registration. However, I am not sure how you set a redirect URI in a SPA. Maybe that is something i need to develop. I use vuejs for my front end and asp.net core mvc for my backend.

Comment: I noticed the options in you set in the api is related to login url and log out url, I'm not sure why you set it..

Comment: Oh I can do a redirect uri for axios requests if a certain error code appears to redirect them to localhost for relogin. That is a great idea and I should have probably done that from the start. Yea I set the login and logout uri so that if the cookie expires it takes them to this custom login page (has my logo on it) which has a button to the MS login. However, I see that is never used anyway even if the cookie expires as you noted because MS still assumes the user is logged in so has no impact like I thought it did.

Comment: ok, when we have a SPA as the client app and an api project as the API server, in this structure, the SPA should use msal.js for integrate AAD for authentication, and with the signed in user, it can also generate access token for calling API. and in the API project, it also need to integrate AAD but no need to set a sign in/out page, it only need to validate the incoming access token, which should work like the sample I shared with you, and that's why I say you may try to comment the `cookieoption` part, api don;t need to check the cookie, when the token is invalid, just return 403/401

Comment: in my humble opinion, it's better for us to follow the structure microsoft provided with us. and that's why I recommend you to follow the official sample..

Comment: We do use MS Graph in our controllers which use the access token so that is why I had this app registered as a traditional web application. But since we use a SPA we probably should have kept the access token on the client/browser side and set this up as a SPA in Azure AD App registration? I am learning a lot from this question so I really appreciate all the comments and answer so far! I will check out that sample. I was using their other samples actually thinking those were most appropriate so I will check the one out you sent which I assume uses a SPA?

Comment: you need to generate access token in SPA, so you can directly call graph api in SPA and no need to put this part in the server. and if you want to call graph api with Application permission, then you don't need to receive access token from SPA...